# c language C:/mingw/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:1706:5: error: unknown type name 'DWORD'

Tags: c

> Contents

What is wrong with you?
I don't understand
I've never tampered with wingdi.h

If it doesn't work, I'll abandon gcc and c　language. I'll make my own compiler and language.
If you criticize me, I'd like to create a service like stackoverflow as a countermeasure.

> What I did

wingdi.h Here's looking at you, kid

```
typedef {
  unsigned int  UINT,
  int           WORD,
  long long     DWORD,
  unsigned char UCHAR,
  byte          BYTE,
  void**        POINT,
}
```

> Environment

windows 10 (64bits)

gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

> souruce

```
// 他のだっとめんどくさいから許してね？w
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <windows.h>

void wingdi__display__write(int win_hei, int win_wid, int display_map);

void main(void){
  wingdi__display__write(1000,1000,0);
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  return 0;
}


//wingdi
void wingdi__display__write(int win_hei, int win_wid, int display_map)
{
  HDC  object    =    NULL,  hdc    =    NULL;
  HWND handle    =    NULL;
  HBRUSH brush   =    NULL;

  hdc            =    GetDC(handle);  
  brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
  SelectObject(object, brush);

  BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, win_wid, win_hei, object, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Comment: That `typedef` block is not valid C. Is that really what the source code looks like?

Comment: I'm a C. What am I doing wrong?I want you to point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support a "block `typedef`" as you have shown; each `typedef` must appear separately as follows:

```
typedef unsigned int  UINT;
typedef int           WORD;
typedef long long     DWORD;
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
typedef uint8_t       BYTE;
typedef void**        POINT;
```

And BTW, it is considered bad practice to hide a pointer type behind a `typedef`, so your `POINT` should be eliminated.

Comment: I think I was mistaken for golang.